# Is there a way to call jquery functions on another object after finishing the first?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to fade out object 1 and after fade out remove a class and add one. After that on another object the object 2 should fadein and then i assign it a class. The problem that i encountered is that if i fire my event faster than the fadein/fadeout the object stays active.

```
        $('.menuA').on("click", function () {
            $('.menuA').removeClass("blue accent-3 z-depth-2", 100);
            let clicked = $(this);
            $('.menuA').promise().done(function () {
                clicked.addClass("blue accent-3 z-depth-2", 100);
            })

            animatePanes($(this).attr("con"));
        })

        function animatePanes(pane) {
            let paneOld = $('.pane-active');
            paneOld.fadeOut(250).removeClass("pane-active").addClass("pane-inactive").promise().done(function () {
                $('.' + pane).fadeIn(250).removeClass("pane-inactive").addClass("pane-active");
            });

        };
```

Thats my event with the function. The problem is that if i click to fast and trigger the event on menuA the paneOld doesnt get the class pane-inactive.

I already tried to do a global variable that checks if the event is running but it didnt worked (probably because i thinked wrong).

Is there a way to disable the event listener until the event is completly finished?

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can surely do it with a global variable - as you've already said. Maybe you just put in in the wrong place.

I'd recommend something like **isAnimating=false** and 'disable' the click event listener if it's value is true. This way you can reset isAnimating to false as soon as all your animations are completed.

```
  var isAnimating = false;
  $('.menuA').on("click", function() {
    if (!isAnimating) {
      $('.menuA').removeClass("blue accent-3 z-depth-2", 100);
      let clicked = $(this);
      $('.menuA').promise().done(function() {
        clicked.addClass("blue accent-3 z-depth-2", 100);
      })

      animatePanes($(this).attr("con"));
      isAnimating = true;
    }
  })

  function animatePanes(pane) {
    let paneOld = $('.pane-active');
    paneOld.fadeOut(250).removeClass("pane-active").addClass("pane-inactive").promise().done(function() {
      $('.' + pane).fadeIn(250).removeClass("pane-inactive").addClass("pane-active").promise().done(function() {
        isAnimating = false;
      });
    });
  }
```

Comment: Oh yeah i see it now... I put isAnimating = false not in the done() statement. Thank you!